# Scala: Returning the constructor of various base classes from a method

Tags: function, scala, constructor

In Scala, I'm trying to return the constructor of a number of base classes from a method as follows

```
Abstract class A
case class B(foo : Int, bar : Int) extends A
case class C(foo : Int) extends A

object D
{
    def foo(bar : Int) : _ => A = 
    {
        bar match
        {
            case 1 => B //return constructor of B
            case 2 => C //return constructor of C
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

D.foo(1)(1,2) //constructs instance of B with parameters (1,2)

D.foo(2)(1) //constructs instance of C with parameters (1)

However, this doesn't work right now

Comment: "However, this doesn't work right now" Please don't do this. In what way does it not work? Not compile? If so, what's the error? Fail at run time?

Comment: And you're attempting to write a function that returns a different type (the two constructors have different types) depending on the input parameter. Although B and C may be subclasses of A, that doesn't mean the types of the constructors for B and C are subtypes of A? So I don't see how the compiler can type check your code - it has no way of telling that when you call foo(1),  the constructor for B is returned, and so the next parameters should be compatible with that. Worse, you could call D.foo(x) for some variable, and then the type of what you're returning varies dynamically at run time

Comment: @Paul I basically wanted it to only return the correct constructor based on the value of bar but not check whether the parameters passed were compatible at compile time. The code Sergey Lagutin provided does that. However, I am aware this is not entirely safe because it doesn't check it at compile time but will just crash at run time if incorrect parameters are passed.

Comment: OK. Seems an odd design to discard type safety in this way, but "as you make your bed, so must you(*) lie in it" as the cliche has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
object D {
  def foo(bar: Int): Seq[Any] => A = {
    seq =>
      bar match {
        case 1 => B(seq(0).asInstanceOf[Int], seq(1).asInstanceOf[Int]) //return constructor of B
        case 2 => C(seq(0).asInstanceOf[Int]) //return constructor of C
      }
  }
}
```

`D.foo` return function which create `A` instance from `seq` params.

Curried version of this code:

```
object D {
  def foo(bar: Int)(seq: Seq[Any]): A =
    bar match {
      case 1 => B(seq(0).asInstanceOf[Int], seq(1).asInstanceOf[Int]) //return constructor of B
      case 2 => C(seq(0).asInstanceOf[Int]) //return constructor of C
    }
}
```

Comment: And produces a run time error if I pass in constructor parameters of the wrong type?

Answer (score 3):

Walk around:

```
abstract class A
case class B(foo : Int, bar : Option[Int]) extends A
case class C(foo : Int, bar : Option[Int]) extends A

implicit def int2option(value : Int) : Option[Int] = Some[value]

object D
{
  def foo(bar : Int) : (Int, Option[Int]) => A =
  {
    bar match
    {
      case 1 => B.apply //return constructor of B
      case 2 => C.apply //return constructor of C
    }
  }
}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val b = D.foo(1)(1, 2)
    val c = D.foo(2)(1, None)

    println(b)
    println(c)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you really want is a factory:

```
trait A {   def foo }

object D {

  private class B extends A {
    def foo(val a: Int, val b:Int): = { println("foo_ab") }
  }

  private class C extends A {
    def foo(cal a: Int): = { println("foo_a") }
  }

  // your 'factory' method
  def apply(bar: Int):A = {
    if (bar == 1) return new B
    else return new C
  }

}
```

From now you can use it:

```
val test = A(1) //Creates a B Object
val test2 = A(2) //creates a C Object
```

I hope this can help you.

I'm extending my answer:

You can do too: `D.apply(1).foo(1,2)` supposing that foo is a method of class B

Comment: How do you can override method `foo` without params by method with params? This code should not compile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm trying to do this with the constructor, not with other methods of the class. Here you returned an object that was initialized with nothing and then applied the method foo to it. I want to be able to return the constructor from the apply method so that the calling entity can initialize the constructor itself with whatever parameters the subclass might have.

Comment: Kariem, see my comment to the question above. You're asking the compiler to predict at compile time what constructor will be returned at run time. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
trait A
case class B(foo : Int, bar : Int) extends A
case class C(foo : Int) extends A

object D
{
    def foo(bar : Int)(x : Int, y: => Int = 0) : A = 
    {
        bar match
        {
            case 1 => B(x,y)
            case 2 => C(x)
        }
    }
}
```

```
scala> val b = D.foo(1)(2,3)
b: A = B(2,3)
scala> val c = D.foo(2)(3)
c: A = C(3)
```

Comment: That works when I know the number and type of the parameters. I was looking for something that can be extended to any number of parameters and any types.